# OpenVPN - Bandwidth throttling a limit to 2 Mbps for both upload/down

Tags: openvpn

I have installed deb package on ubuntu 14.04 x64 for two VPS servers. DigitalOcean and Ramnode and have the same results. I connect with client and I run speed test. I get the same result for both VPSs which is 2Mbps limit on up/down. Of course I get insane speeds when testing the servers by themselves, 100+ Mbps up/down so its not the servers unless there throttling specific openvpn protocol or port. My own connection 100/10 Mbps. This very strange something throttling it. Hopefully not my ISP. What am I doing wrong? Using openvpn access server, should I just go to command line install, apt-get?

Comment: Please provide some system metrics (like CPU, memory usage)

Comment: Used both the smallest vps servers for both vps. For 512MBMemory and 1 Core Processor, wouldn't i max at higher speed. 2mbs for both upload and down seems low.

Answer (score 0):

Try ShadowsocksR, it is much more immune to ISP throttling.

A tutorial: https://www.tipsforchina.com/how-to-setup-a-fast-shadowsocks-server-on-vultr-vps-the-easy-way.html

You can then use something like Proxifier to tunnel your whole system through the proxy.